# Run PHP script on all pages

Tags: php

I am working on a project and I need to run the same php script on every page or before loading the page.

I want the actual `<? /*code here*/?>` on every page on the server.

Is there any way to pull of something like this?

Comment: Two ideas for you: 1. http://davidwalsh.name/prepend-append-files-htaccess, 2. http://www.sitepoint.com/front-controller-pattern-1/

Comment: I went looking to see if the solution I posted was applicable outside of Apache and found the older question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a single file act as a controller that loads all your other files (perhaps index.php) is a common way, but if that's not possible, I'd suggest prepend files as mentioned by Matt Browne. (Apache dependent.) I actually did an append to force a footer on a site that was all static pages. I had to do it in php.ini, not .htaccess.

```
# Append file to bottom of page
auto_append_file = '/home/mycustomer/public_html/sub_footer.php'
```

So, yours could be

```
# Prepend file to top of page
auto_prepend_file = '/yourpath/pre_header.php'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Include` function at the beginning of your body tag,

**vars.php** :

```
<?php
  $color = 'green';
  $fruit = 'apple';
?>
```

**test.php** :

```
<?php
  echo "A $color $fruit"; // A
  include 'vars.php';
  echo "A $color $fruit"; // A green apple
?>
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 0):

You should use [include()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). Here is an example of it:

**vars.php**

```
<?php

$color = 'green';
$fruit = 'apple';

?>
```

**test.php**

```
echo "A $color $fruit"; // A

include 'vars.php';

echo "A $color $fruit"; // A green apple

?>
```